# Simple program crashes

Tags: c++, gcc, crash, g++

So I've been using MinGW GCC version 4.4 or a while, and decided it's time to upgrade. I went to the MinGW website and downloaded the latest version of GCC (4.7.0).

After deleting my previous version, and installing the newest version, even the simplest program will crash. For example, if I compile this program

```c
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    cout << "Hello, World" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

with the command line

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe
```

It will print out "Hello, World" and then crash. However, if I compile it with the following command line:

```
g++ -O3 hello.cpp -o hello.exe
```

It will run perfectly fine, without crashing at all.

Now, if I change the input program, and make it slightly more complicated:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string str;

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline (cin, str);

    if (str == "foo")
        cout << "You entered foo!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "You entered: " << str;

    return 0;
}
```

Without the optimization option (-O3), it will crash before printing out "Enter a string: ", however, with the code optimization line, it crashes after entering a string.

Now, finally to my question. What can I do to fix this, will I simply have to revert to a previous version of GCC in order to use it? Also, why would GCC not be compiling a simple program correctly?

---

**Update:** The error was caused by the GCC installation, when installing with the MinGW installer, and choosing the option to "Download latest repository catalogues", it would reproduce the error. However, if I used the same installer and chose "Use pre-packaged repository catalogues", then the error no longer exists. So there is some error in the latest version of the binaries listed in the MinGW GCC catalogues.

Comment: Sounds like you borked your debugging library. The fact that optimizations "solves" the problem means that the release run-time libraries are fine. But the debug run-time libraries are somehow misconfigured.

Comment: But he said it crashes with optimizations enabled.

Comment: So maybe something went wrong with the GCC installation, potentially something got corrupted? I'll redownload and reinstall it to see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd do too. If a completely clean install doesn't fix it, try another machine. If it repros, then it's probably a bug in the installer.

Comment: I redownloaded and reinstalled with the exact same options as I did last time, and I still received the same problem. So I removed it and installed it again with different options and GCC now works. It appears as though there's something wrong with the latest version of GCC. When I install with the option "Download latest repository catalogues", it will reproduce the error. However, if I install with "Use pre-packaged repository catalogues", it will compile and run both example programs perfectly.

Comment: May be you didn't remove some old libraries, or include files and use it. Try `g++ hello.cpp --verbose` (or `g++ hello.cpp --verbose 2>&1 | grep "4.4"`)

Comment: While the 'offical' MinGW installation support seems to have improved a lot since the days when I found it impossible to figure out, I have a hard time moving away from nuwen's nice and simple "just unzip it somewhere" installer: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html  I've also never had a problem with TDM's 'bundle' installer: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download

Comment: I still don't understand why people are so reluctant to use a debugger. gcc even supports combining of -O and -g switches, and if it crashes with MingW's latest repository versions, it would be nice to file a bug report including a stack trace if not yet done by someone else.

Comment: This is a bug in GCC 4.7. You can monitor its status here:
https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3588678&group_id=2435&atid=102435

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've ran into very similar problem, where a release build was fine and a debug build was broken. The solution was to perorm the following:

```
mingw-get update
mingw-get upgrade
mingw-get install gcc g++ mingw32-make --reinstall
```

This might have been a double-kill, but at least it even helped when "upgrade" could not remove some previous libraries.

Comment: I attempted to do that, redownloaded the latest version of gcc, and entered those three commands to update, upgrade, and reinstall. However, it will still create a program that will crash. So far, the only way I've been able to get it to work is to use the "pre-packaged repository catalogues", which causes gcc 4.6.2 to be installed instead of 4.7.0